# No matching distribution found for torch==1.5.0+cpu on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, pytorch, torch

I am trying to deploy my Django app which uses a machine learning model. And the machine learning model requires pytorch to execute.
When i am trying to deploy it is giving me this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.5.0+cpu (from -r /tmp/build_4518392d43f43bc52f067241a9661c92/requirements.txt (line 23)) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 0.4.1, 0.4.1.post2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1.post2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0)
       ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.5.0+cpu (from -r /tmp/build_4518392d43f43bc52f067241a9661c92/requirements.txt (line 23))
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

My requirements.txt is

```
asgiref==3.2.7
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.6
django-heroku==0.3.1
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
imageio==2.8.0
kiwisolver==1.2.0
matplotlib==3.2.1
numpy==1.18.4
Pillow==7.1.2
psycopg2==2.8.5
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.23.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
torch==1.5.0+cpu
torchvision==0.6.0+cpu
urllib3==1.25.9
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

And runtime.txt is `python-3.7.5`
However installing it on my computer is not giving any type of error when i use command `pip install torch==1.5.0+cpu` I am using python 3.7.5 and pip 20.0.2. 
Complete code is [here](https://github.com/av1shek/mlapps).
How to solve this issue i really need to deploy my app. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

PyTorch does not distribute the CPU only versions over PyPI. They are only available through their custom registry.

If you select the CPU only version on [PyTorch - Get Started Locally](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) you get the following instructions:

```sh
pip install torch==1.5.0+cpu torchvision==0.6.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Since you're not manually executing the pip install, you cannot simply add the `-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`.

As an alternative, you can put it into your `requirements.txt` as a standalone line. It shouldn't really matter where exactly you put it, but it is commonly put at the very top.

```
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
asgiref==3.2.7
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.6
django-heroku==0.3.1
future==0.18.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
imageio==2.8.0
kiwisolver==1.2.0
matplotlib==3.2.1
numpy==1.18.4
Pillow==7.1.2
psycopg2==2.8.5
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.23.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
torch==1.5.0+cpu
torchvision==0.6.0+cpu
urllib3==1.25.9
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a torch expert, but I've seen a similar issue with other AI packages that require C compilers and/or additional libraries.

1. See if there is a "buildpack" available on Heroku that will install those dependencies, or
2. Change to using the "container" method of distribution, where you build and push docker images to heroku as your deployment strategy.

Comment: For Pytorch CPU version no C compiler/ or additional libraries required those are required for Pytorch GPU version. And can you please explain your 2nd point i m not getting what you want to say I m newbie in deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried my project to install torch 1.5.0 but it is supporting my local machine but when I deploying it in Heroku it is getting an error. when I put below
requiremenmts.txt it is working fine
always remember it needs to give initially from line no.1
requirements.txt:
1     `-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`
2    `torch== 1.8.1+cpu`
3.   `torchvision==0.9.1+cpu`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this for those still having issues.

Make sure you have `-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`
at the start of your **requirements.txt**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using too new or too old version of Python, in my case, I was using `FROM python:3` in my `Dockerfile`. I changed it to `From python:3.7` and the error went away.